# Django: redirect admin logout to allauth login

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-allauth

I'm using the django-allauth login page to log users into my admin panel. This works fine, but when they logout from the admin panel, I want them to be sent directly back to the /accounts/login/ page (**preferably to /accounts/login/?next=/admin/surveys/survey/**), rather than to the /admin/logout/ page that says "thank you for spending quality time with the site." I tried the LOGOUT_URL property in my settings file, but it doesn't seem to do what I'm describing above. Here's some of my relevant code:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from mysite import views

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='landingpage.html'), name='landingpage'),
    url(r'^surveys/', include('surveys.urls', namespace="surveys")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^submitfeedback/$', views.submitfeedback, name='submitfeedback'),

    # tried this but it didn't work: url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/accounts/login/'}),
    # tried this but it didn't work: url(r'^admin/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/accounts/login/'}),

    ## below for django-allauth
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
)

# settings.py

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/admin/surveys/survey/"
LOGOUT_URL = "/accounts/login/"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is not in views.py but in the template itself.  What you want to do is copy the admin/base.html file (seen on Github [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) into your projects templates folder -- which you can then overwrite as needed.  This template has all the header information that is inherited by the rest of the admin templates.  Find the line that reads:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
```

and simply change that to:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
```

And it should now follow the format of the allauth logout on the rest of your site.

Comment: Thanks! That got me almost what I needed -- after implementing your suggestion, it took me to this annoying accounts/logout page asking if I really want to logout. Ended up figuring out that I could put this in my urls.py to get me where I actually wanted to go: url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/accounts/login/?next=/admin/surveys/survey/'}),

Answer (score 6):

Add `url(r'^admin/logout/$', 'yourappname.views.signout')` in `urls.py` before including `admin.site.urls` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/logout/$', 'yourappname.views.signout'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('appname.urls'))
]
```

Of course, in your app, you should define a signout view:

```
def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('yourappname:index')) # or wherever you want
```

Comment: For those who are new to Django, like me `from django.contrib.auth import logout`, `from django.shortcuts import redirect` and `from django.urls import reverse` may be useful.

Answer (score -1):

This question is as old as the hills (it's now 2023, Django 4.2.4) and you can achieve this by adding to your project's url.py.

```
import allauth.account.views
...
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/logout/", allauth.account.views.logout),
    ...
]
```

This will logout and send you back to allauth's signin.
Seperately, The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` can be set to your desired redirect (`/admin/surveys/survey/` for OP)